# colocar suma dado una sentencia Case

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, usecase, rowsums

espero se encuentren bien, acá de nuevo para solicitar de su apoyo. tengo una consulta, pero no logro que dentro del case me el resultado según sea la promoción (Juego Completo o Nacional), el resultado me da el mismo dato y debería aparecer solo en la opción que el socio/cliente adquirió.

ejemplo de lo que requiero:

```
N_Socio----Nombre_socio------------------------------Juego_completo - Nacional

30001234--ANTONIA GOMEZ ALVAREZ-----------------------     2       --------------   -
```

aqui el query que ocupo.

```
SELECT N_Socio, Nombre_socio,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL([Juego_Completo],0) < 0 THEN '-' ELSE Cantidad END AS Juego_completo,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL([Nacional],0) < 0 THEN '-' ELSE Cantidad END AS Nacional   
        FROM (
            SELECT t.[Customer No_] AS N_Socio, c.[Name] AS Nombre_socio, 
                CASE t.[Promotion No_]
                WHEN 'PR0000002569' THEN 'Juego_Completo'
                WHEN 'PR0000002568' THEN 'Juego_Completo'
                WHEN 'PR0000002571' THEN 'Nacional'
                WHEN 'PR0000002570' THEN 'Nacional'
                END AS Promocion,
                CEILING(-sum(t.[Quantity])/8) AS Cantidad               
            FROM [CG008].[dbo].[CIGA$Trans_ Sales Entry] t 
                INNER JOIN [CG008].[dbo].[CIGA$Offer] o  
                ON t.[Promotion No_] = o.[No_]  
                INNER JOIN [CG008].[dbo].[CIGA$Customer] c  
                ON t.[Customer No_] = c.[No_]
        WHERE [Promotion No_] IN 
            ('PR0000002571','PR0000002570','PR0000002569','PR0000002568')
            AND c.[No_] IS NOT NULL AND c.[Name] IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY t.[Customer No_], c.[Name], t.[Promotion No_]
) AS s
PIVOT (
    COUNT(Promocion) FOR Promocion IN ([Juego_Completo],[Nacional])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY N_socio
```

Comment: Leí tu pregunta dos veces y no sé que es lo que buscas. Considero que a tu pregunta le falta un ejemplo de los datos de entrada, la salida esperada y una explicación, en lenguaje coloquial, de dicha salida o de cómo llegar a ella.

Comment: Que tal bro, un saludo.
el ejemplo de lo que requiero lo plasme en la consulta, no se por que no puedes visualizarlo.
con el query que coloque me coloca en ambos casos del case el resultado total por juego, y lo que requería es que colocara la cantidad de juegos comprados segun el tipo de compra.

N_Socio----Nombre_socio------------------------------Juego_completo - Nacional



30001234--ANTONIA GOMEZ ALVAREZ-----------------------     2       -------------- x -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema parece ser que estás agrupando por el código de promoción cuando deberías estar agrupando por la descripción. En lo personal, cambiaría el CASE por un JOIN a una tabla generada al vuelo. Así se ve más limpia la consulta y es más fácil la agrupación.

```
WITH ctePromociones AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ( 'PR0000002569', 'Juego_Completo'),
                 ( 'PR0000002568', 'Juego_Completo'),
                 ( 'PR0000002571', 'Nacional'      ),
                 ( 'PR0000002570', 'Nacional'      ))p([Promotion No_], Promocion)
)
SELECT N_Socio, 
     Nombre_socio,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL([Juego_Completo],0) < 0 THEN '-' ELSE Cantidad END AS Juego_completo,
     CASE WHEN ISNULL([Nacional],0) < 0 THEN '-' ELSE Cantidad END AS Nacional   
FROM (
            SELECT  t.[Customer No_] AS N_Socio, 
                    c.[Name] AS Nombre_socio, 
                    p.Promocion,
                    CEILING(-sum(t.[Quantity])/8) AS Cantidad               
            FROM       [CG008].[dbo].[CIGA$Trans_ Sales Entry]    t 
            INNER JOIN [CG008].[dbo].[CIGA$Offer]                 o ON t.[Promotion No_] = o.[No_]  
            INNER JOIN [CG008].[dbo].[CIGA$Customer]              c ON t.[Customer No_]  = c.[No_]
            INNER JOIN ctePromociones                             p ON t.[Promotion No_] = p.t.[Promotion No_]
            --Ya no se necesita porque estamos filtrando con el INNER JOIN
            --WHERE [Promotion No_] IN ('PR0000002571','PR0000002570','PR0000002569','PR0000002568')
            AND   c.[No_] IS NOT NULL 
            AND   c.[Name] IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY t.[Customer No_], 
             c.[Name], 
             p.Promocion
) AS s
PIVOT (
    COUNT(Promocion) FOR Promocion IN ([Juego_Completo],[Nacional])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY N_socio;
```

Aunque siendo realistas, creo que me desharía de la instrucción PIVOT por completo para usar un agregado condicional que me da más flexibilidad al momento de convertir filas en columnas.

```
SELECT  t.[Customer No_] AS N_Socio, 
        c.[Name] AS Nombre_socio, 
        COUNT( CASE WHEN t.[Promotion No_] IN( 'PR0000002568', 'PR0000002569') THEN 1 END)'Juego_Completo',
        COUNT( CASE WHEN t.[Promotion No_] IN( 'PR0000002570', 'PR0000002571') THEN 1 END)'Nacional',
        CEILING(-sum(t.[Quantity])/8) AS Cantidad               
FROM       [CG008].[dbo].[CIGA$Trans_ Sales Entry] t 
INNER JOIN [CG008].[dbo].[CIGA$Offer]              o ON t.[Promotion No_] = o.[No_]  
INNER JOIN [CG008].[dbo].[CIGA$Customer]           c ON t.[Customer No_]  = c.[No_]
WHERE [Promotion No_] IN  ('PR0000002571','PR0000002570','PR0000002569','PR0000002568')
AND c.[No_] IS NOT NULL 
AND c.[Name] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY N_socio;
```

Comment: Que tal @Luis Cazeres... de antemano te agradezco mucho por la mega ayuda, siempre es grato contar con el apoyo de la comunidad y sobre todo cuando te sugieren como mejorar. 
Saludos y muchas nuevamente gracias... la sugerencia/corrección quedo genial!

N_Socio--Nombre_socio----Juego_Completo---Nacional---Cantidad
30000136--ANTONIA GOMEZ ALVAREZ----16---0---2